# T.Less does not match inferred type func(a T, b T) int for func(a E, b E) int

Tags: go, generics

I'm pretty much seeing these errors when i run `go run main.go`. All the errors are from a different package.

```
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/bobg/go-generics/v2@v2.2.1/slices/dropin.go:150:21: type func(a E, b E) bool of less does not match inferred type func(a E, b E) int for func(a E, b E) int
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/bobg/go-generics/v2@v2.2.1/slices/dropin.go:156:27: type func(a E, b E) bool of less does not match inferred type func(a E, b E) int for func(a E, b E) int
../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/bobg/go-generics/v2@v2.2.1/slices/dropin.go:167:32: type func(a E, b E) bool of less does not match inferred type func(a E, b E) int for func(a E, b E) int
```

I have run `go clean -modcache`. I have changed my go version to 1.20 and 1.21. Not sure what else I can do here?

Comment: yeah reopened. unfortunately, the Go issue this points to doesn't exist anymore https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61991

Comment: Yah I used that issue's code, but the solution doesn't exist

Comment: @anu do you have a minimal repro that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: The issue is not my code. It's not compiling because of the above error in a indirect dependency in my go mod.

Answer (score 1):

*The error:*

The error points happens in that library: https://github.com/bobg/go-generics
at version 2.2.1, in file `slices/dropin.go`:
https://github.com/bobg/go-generics/blob/v2.2.1/slices/dropin.go#L150

l.150 (as well as 156 and 167) depends on the `golang.org/x/exp/slices` package.

It turns out that a commit landed in [`golang.org/x/exp`](https://github.com/golang/exp/tree/master/slices) which changes the signature of the sorting functions, and breaks backward compatibility :

https://github.com/golang/exp/commit/302865e7556b4ae5de27248ce625d443ef4ad3ed

> **slices: update to current standard library version**
>
> Update x/exp/slices to the current standard library slices package,
> while retaining the ability to use it with Go 1.18 through Go 1.20.
>
> Note that this changes some of the sorting functions to use a
> comparison function rather than a less function. We don't promise
> backward compatibility in x/exp packages. Being compatible with the
> Go 1.21 package seems more useful for people not yet using 1.21,
> as it will make the transition to 1.21 easier.
>
> The generated files were built using "go generate" with a GOROOT
> that included CL 511660.
>
> Fixes golang/go#61374

(you can see the changes to the `SortFunc` function [here](https://github.com/golang/exp/commit/302865e7556b4ae5de27248ce625d443ef4ad3ed#diff-ec22fd7f0aec27f1c6dc503e7dd3960c8f5ab781684218aa59b404ada0d48231R29))

If your project pulls one of the latest versions of `golang.org/x/exp`, then that version can not be compiled together with `github.com/bobg/go-generics@v2.2.1`.

*note*: the [`golang.org/x/exp`](https://github.com/golang/exp) package was created to try experimentations and explicitly states that new versions may break existing code:

> **Warning:** Packages here are experimental and unreliable. Some may one day be promoted to the main repository or other subrepository, or they may be modified arbitrarily or even disappear altogether.

---

*The fix:*

Starting from version 3.0.0, project https://github.com/bobg/go-generics stopped depending on `golang.org/x/exp` and started using the new `slices` package, which appeared in the standard library with go v1.21.

If you update the version for go-generics to its latest version, it should compile correctly. You may have to adapt other parts of your code (either your own code, or other third party libraries) to make them work with the new signature.

Depending on what you use in `go-generics`, you may perhaps drop that dependency entirely and use the new `slices`, `maps` and `cmp` packages from the standard library.